# How to copy xlsx-File without locking it for Excel

Tags: c#, excel, copy

I'm currently trying to write a method that copies files without preventing other applications from changing them. If there was a change while reading I will just read it again.

This works fine when I change the files in Notepad while they are read. But when I try to save the file in Excel 2010 I get the message "{FileName} is currently in use. Try again later."

I tried this using .NET Framework 3.5 and .NET Framework 4.0.

```
int partsToReadAtOnce = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
bool fileChangedDuringWrite = false;
using (FileStream readStr = new FileStream(srcPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    using (FileStream writeStr = new FileStream(targetPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None))
    {
        do
        {
            DateTime srcWriteTimeBefore = new FileInfo(srcPath).LastWriteTime;
            writeStr.SetLength(0);
            readStr.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            byte[] curData = new byte[partsToReadAtOnce];
            int len = 1;
            while ((len = readStr.Read(curData, 0, partsToReadAtOnce)) != 0)
            {
                writeStr.Write(curData, 0, len);
            }

            // break here and try to write to the file
            FileInfo srcInfo = new FileInfo(srcPath);
            FileInfo targetInfo = new FileInfo(targetPath);
            fileChangedDuringWrite = srcInfo.LastWriteTime.Ticks != srcWriteTimeBefore.Ticks
                || srcInfo.Length != targetInfo.Length;
        } while (fileChangedDuringWrite);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is, Notepad doesn't lock files (it reads the file into memory and you edit the in-memory version) whereas Excel locks the file

I don't think there is a way save opening the spreadsheet in read-only mode or creating a copy.

If you need to copy I don't think you need to lock the file (I'm sure you can open for read only)

Have you tried changing your access to read?

Edit: ah yes you have!

Check this answer out: [Beginner Python: Saving an excel file while it is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995612/beginner-python-saving-an-excel-file-while-it-is-open)

It addresses the same issue (and there doesn't appear to be a good workaround)

You could put the locked files into a list and come back to them. There is no reason you can't handle the exception, put the file into a queue, continue with the other files and come back to the start again after you are done with the rest (with a delay).

At least this way there's a chance the user has finished with the file by the time you revisit

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not excel locking the file, the problem is my program locking the excel-file while it is reading so Excel can't save it. In my understanding this should not happen because I'm just reading with FileShare.ReadWrite. I can't implement retries on my side because the users/macros I don't have control over need to retry. I want to prevent this.

Comment: Someone suggests here that they got it working in that manner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730565/error-opening-streamreader-because-file-is-used-by-another-process - but it looks like you are already using this approach with `FileShare.ReadWrite`

Comment: Jup, that's what I'm wondering - Excel 2010 seems to block saving the file while it is read in shared mode what according to MSDN "Allows subsequent opening of the file for reading or writing". It does - for Notepad, but not for Excel (reading works fine, but not saving), there seem to be some extra checks made by Excel, at least in Excel 2010.